# Activate iOS Application when remote notification with data is received

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm creating an iOS application for two factor authentication.
I have a system where the user logs in and my server sends a challenge via remote notification (push message) to my iOS app.

I am able to receive the push notification when the app is not activated, so that's fine.
What I am not able to do is to activate my app. I don't know how to do it.
The push message contains structured data (not a simple alert text message).

Is it possible? Can I set some flag in the push message? Or is this one of those things that violates iOS guidelines?

Comment: I don't think you can activate iOS app with push.

Comment: If by "activate" you mean bring the app to the foreground, no, you can't. It could be very disruptive to the user. If the user allows it then you can display a notification that when tapped will launch your app with the notification payload.

Answer (score 0):

go to App Settings -> Capabilites and turn on Background Modes for your app. Check the last option, Remote Notifications, 
to know more about it check this tutorial :
[This raywenderlich tutorial  is all u need to get up and running with push notification](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started)

---

if that didn't work add : 'content_available' => true  to your push notification  parameters 
ex :

```
{
   "alert" :"",
    "badge" :"787",
      "Content-available" : "1" // or true,
       "sound" : ""
        }
```

If you provide this key with a value of 1, (if user opens you app is in background or resumed) the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: will be called.

According to RemoteNotifications Programming content-available definition is

> Provide this key with a value of 1 to indicate that new content is available. Including this key and value means that when your app is launched in the background or resumed, application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is called.(Newsstand apps are guaranteed to be able to receive at least one push with this key per 24-hour window.)

Comment: I think he wants to activate the app, as opposed to running code in background mode. The question specifically states that he is able to receive messages in the background, but not to active the app.

Comment: then he can open the link that i given him above and search in the page  for :
 "Silent Push Notifications"
 he will find exactly what he is looking for in details.

Comment: From my understanding, Silent Push Notifications will not allow you to activate the app. It will allow you to run code, sure, but to activate it, no.

Comment: exactly , but the       "Content-available" : "1"  and  Settings -> Capabilites and turn on Background Modes for the app, will surely do.

Comment: so it's up to him to see what will fill his need is it to use silent push notification to wake his app up silently to perform some tasks in the background Or  add the      "Content-available" : "1" parameter which will coz the app activation.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Apple Documentation about [Creating the Remote Notification PayLoad](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1) and look for "Configuring a Background Update Notification". Just keep in mind this will not work if your application is force quit. Make sure your application is showing in AppSwitcher but in an inactive mode means you haven't used from a long time.